# Is there an inflection point in Coronavirus outbreaks where you can't contain the epidemy anymore?

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, epidemiology

So far only a few countries have been able to reduce through policies the number of people infected in their countries after being exposed to thousands of infected, viz. China (including Taiwan, Hong Kong), Singapore, and South Korea. In Europe, several countries have been trying to reduce the number of infected people or the number of new cases through quarantines, and after 1 or 2 weeks, it doesn't seem to me that their measures are working. Are they?

Is there an inflection point in Coronavirus outbreak where you can't contain the epidemic anymore?

Comment: China reduced cases only by isolation that has lasted months. Their slowing in deaths is comparable to Italy but Italy started much later.

Comment: Are you asking about sending diagnosed and their (known) contacts into quarantine or about a quarantine for (almost) everyone in a given region, regardless of whether they were found to be SARS-CoV-2 positive or not?